# How do I open the dash when a fullscreen application has the focus? (12.10 13.04)

Tags: 12.10, unity, unity-dash, 13.04

When I press the "windows" key the dash normally opens. When I press it when a fullscreen window has the focus, it doesn't seem to do anything. How do I open the dash when a fullscreen window has the focus?

I have seen this problem in 12.10 and 13.04 with Unity3D.

Comment: Unity 2D or 3D?

Comment: 12.04 unity 3D too; I have to change workspace.

Comment: Tried Unity 2D?

Comment: Unity 3D has the problem. I have not tried Unity 2D. I am under the impression that 2D is no longer supported as of 12.10.

Comment: Unity 2D is removed from newer versions of 12.04. Unity 3D is standard.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, when you press the "super" key when a full screen application is in focus, the dash opens, but it can't gain "paint" focus, as the application is still at the top of the stack. But strangely, the dash has the keyboard focus.

As far as I know, there is no way to see the dash when a full screen application is working. Only way is to get out of full screen, and then press "windows" key to get the dash.

Comment: ... or [Ctrl] + [Alt] + [→] (or [←] / [↑] / [↓]) to another workspace.

Comment: i think the terms **super key** or **meta key** (rather than **windows key**) are more appropriate here :)